# Linux: how does deadlocked process look in top?

Tags: linux, process, deadlock

Would it be in the bottom of the list as it most likely would be blocked waiting for some system resource?

Comment: Most likely it would be in state of waiting for some resource. But if process runs other threads, these threads may produce some load.

Comment: @CyberDem0n I would like to know where would it show up in the output of top command

Comment: "It depends". If the process is single threaded and deadlocked, then it's in a wait/sleep state and not using any CPU time, so it would be lower on the list (although among sleeping processes, the order seems somewhat arbitrary). If it's multithreaded with only one thread deadlocked, it may be at the top of the list, as it may still be utilizing CPU time... `top` is most likely not a very good indicator of deadlock...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the way deadlocked processes are blocked.

Suppose they are blocked on a spin lock, then they might show 
up in the first lines of top output.

On the other hand, if processes are sleeping waiting (forever) for a resource, then it's likely they won't appear in the first lines of top output